# Determining the infimum of a supremum

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I want to determine the value of the following term

$$\inf \bigg\{\sup \bigg\{ \frac{2n}{2+n(-1)^n}:n>k\bigg\}:k\in\mathbb N\bigg\}$$

The main problem why I cannot solve this by my own is that the $(-1)^n$ is really disturbing me. Its hard for me to control the bevaviour of the inner term (hard to now what the supremum is).

If anyone could help me, I would be really happy.

Comment: Try to study separately the subsequences corresponding to $n$ even and $n$ odd, that is $\frac{2(2h)}{2+2h}$ and $\frac{2(2h+1)}{2-(2h+1)}, h \in \mathbb{N}$. Both of them are monotone.

Answer (score 1):

Recall the following first (it is for some people the definition of $\limsup$) :
\begin{align} \limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n = \inf_{k\in\mathbb{N}} \left(\sup_{n>k} a_n\right) 
\end{align} 
Then it is easy:
\begin{align} 
\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n = \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{2n}{2+n(-1)^n} = 2
\end{align} 
Conclude.

Answer (score 0):

For a fixed $k\in \mathbb{N}$, the limit of $\frac{2n}{2+n(-1)^n} | n>k$ as $n\to \infty$ is $(-1)^n 2$, hence the supremum is clearly $2$, and note that this is independent of the value $k$.

Therefore, the inner set generates always the value $2$ independent of the value of $k$, hence the infinitum is again 2.